# jsonschema: external nested reference

Tags: jsonschema

##### Summary

I'd like to have a schema A that refers to another schema B, where B contains a `$ref` to nested `$defs`. But when I try this, I get file-not-found errors because jsonschema searches for `$defs` in the wrong path.

What should the `$ref` paths look like to get this to work?

##### JSON Schemas

Currently, my schemas look like:

A: `$(pwd)/my-foo.com/schemas/parent-nested.schema.json`:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "my-foo.com/schemas/parent-nested.schema.json",
    "description": "A schema that references a nested external schema.",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["child"],
    "properties": {
        "child": {
            "$ref": "nested.schema.json"
        }
    }
}
```

B: `$(pwd)/my-foo.com/schemas/nested.schema.json`:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "my-foo.com/schemas/nested.schema.json",
    "description": "Schema that refers to nested definitions.",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["val"],
    "properties": {
        "val": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/value"
        }
    },
    "$defs": {
        "value": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["data"],
            "properties": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### Problem Details

When I validate json directly against B, it works, so its `$defs` section *seems* to be ok:

```
echo '{"val": {"data": "something"}}' | jsonschema --base-uri "file://$(pwd)/" my-foo.com/schemas/nested.schema.json
```

However, when I try to validate against A, jsonschema throws an error:

```
echo '{"child": {"val": {"data": "something"}}}' | jsonschema --base-uri "file://$(pwd)/" my-foo.com/schemas/parent-nested.schema.json
```

> ```
> "/Users/USERNAME/.pyenv/versions/3.9.10/envs/dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 909, in resolve_from_url
>     document = self.store[url]   File "/Users/USERNAME/.pyenv/versions/3.9.10/envs/dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jsonschema/_utils.py",
> line 28, in __getitem__
>     return self.store[self.normalize(uri)] KeyError: 'file:///Users/USERNAME/code/jsonschema-practice/external-refs/my-foo.com/schemas/my-foo.com/schemas/nested.schema.json'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/USERNAME/.pyenv/versions/3.9.10/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py",
> line 1503, in open_local_file
>     stats = os.stat(localfile) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/Users/USERNAME/code/jsonschema-practice/external-refs/my-foo.com/schemas/my-foo.com/schemas/nested.schema.json'/
> ```

(note the duplication of `my-foo.com/schemas/my-foo.com/schemas` in the path)

If I change B's `val` schema from `"$ref": "#/$defs/value"` to `"type": "object"`, eliminating the `$def` ref, validating against A works, so jsonschema is at least able to find B's schema file originally.

But it seems like in trying to resolve the self-referential `$def`, it's duplicating base-uri when it tries to lookup the nested definition.

Is there a different way I should be specifying the paths in the schema or the base-uri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema identifiers must be absolute. Your `$id`s are relative, so the schema identifier is determined by resolving the `$id` against the URI used to retrieve the schema (the retrieval URI).

- **Base URI**: `file:///path/to/project/my-foo.com/schemas/parent-nested.schema.json`
- **$id**: `my-foo.com/schemas/parent-nested.schema.json`
- **Schema Identifier**: `file:///path/to/project/my-foo.com/schemas/my-foo.com/schemas/parent-nested.schema.json`

When the `$ref` resolves against that schema identifier, you end up with `file:///path/to/project/my-foo.com/schemas/my-foo.com/schemas/nested.schema.json` which isn't the right path the schema you're trying to reference and you get an error.

My recommendation is to not use `$id`. This is especially true if you're working with schemas that will be retrieved from the filesystem or over http(s). The retrieval URI is sufficient for schema identification. In these cases, `$id` provides no value and can only lead to problems like the one you've encountered. `$id`s only make sense when the schemas are loaded in memory and don't have a retrieval URI.

If you really want to keep the `$id`s, your choices are to either shorten it to just the file name (no path), or use an absolute URI.