# How to call a Json schema to another schema using #ref

Tags: json-schema-validator

I want to use a generic Json pattern (**genericPattern.json**) in another schema(**car.json**)

**car.json**

```
{"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema#",
    "$id": "https://test.com/car.schema.json",
    "title": "car",
    "description": "A car",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "date": {
             "$ref": "./genericPattern.json#/patterns/DatePattern"
        }
   }
}
```

**genericPattern.json**

````
"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema#",
    "title": "GenericPatterns",
    "description": "Generic Patterns",
    "patterns": {
        "DatePattern": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "mypattern",
            "message": {
                "pattern": "Correct pattern is mypattern "
            }
        }
}```

I have both schema in the .war file, same directory, but I got allways this error:
````

Error 500: com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaException: #/properties/date/$ref: Reference ./genericPattern.json#/patterns/DatePattern cannot be resolved
``

If i use: *"$id": "https://test.com/car.schema.json"*, I got:

`Error 500: com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaException: java.net.UnknownHostException: test.com`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use a generic component file to maintain multiple types, you can define it with the `$defs` collection.

Your use of `message` is ignored by the JSON Schema validator, this is not a recognized keyword.

The use of `$id` will also depend on which validator you are using and how you load your schemas for validation, whether from the file system, over http, or a schema registry. This answer provides consideration for the `$id` attribute.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76419307/8564731

The following composed schema validates successfully based on the `pattern: mypattern` constraint. Adjust the pattern according to your requirements.

```json
{
    "$id": "https://test.com/genericPatterns",
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "title": "GenericPatterns",
    "description": "Generic Patterns",
    "$defs": {
        "DatePattern": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "mypattern",
            "message": {
                "pattern": "Correct pattern is mypattern "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can reference it

```json
{
    "$id": "https://test.com/car.schema.json",
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "title": "car",
    "description": "A car",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "date": {
            "$ref": "genericPatterns#/$defs/DatePattern"
        }
    }
}
```

```json
#false
{
    date: "2020-12-12",
}

#true
{
    date: "mypattern"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i got the same error  ```error 500: com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaException: #/properties/date/$ref: Reference genericPattern#/$defs/DatePattern cannot be resolved ```

Comment: the interceptor load json schema in a ```private static final Map<Class<?>, JsonSchema> jsonSchemas = new HashMap<>();static {   jsonSchemas.put(Class1.class, createJsonSchema("WEB-INF/schema/car.json"));}```, Isn t other way to load all the schema, not one by one for specify class